# How to get file size in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, file-upload

I want to get file size. Currently I used `get_headers` function of php to get file size by Url.

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/magento2/pub/media/myfolder/m/a/myfile.zip";
$data = get_headers($url, true);
if (isset($data['Content-Length']))
echo (int) $data['Content-Length'];
```

But how can we do this in Magento 2 ?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. I just give you a suggestion: `\Magento\Downloadable\Helper\File` -> `$this->_mediaDirectory->stat($file)['size']`

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Thanks. It's working perfectly which i want . But it's get size in bytes how we convert it as MB, KB in Magento 2?

Comment: hello, don't check Magento yet, but seem that we can convert from byte to mega byte easily.

Comment: Yes I already do with core php. But is there any function or class in Magento 2 to convert byte to MB or KB size?

Comment: Take a look here: `vendor/magento/framework/File/Size.php`